# Passing objects in C++ gives 'invalid use of non-static member' error

Tags: c++, pointers, object, methods, scope

So, I'm making a game in which when the thrower(a ball) lands on the trampoline, I need to make the thrower's speed change.
I already have a function called `detect_collision` in `main` which is in the file `main.cpp`

So, in the trampoline class, I have this function:

trampoline.cpp:

```
#include "trampoline.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "thrower.h"

//other functions

void Trampoline::landed(Thrower* thrower){
    if (detect_collision(this->bounding_box, thrower->bounding_box))
        thrower->speed.y = -2* thrower->speed.y;
  }
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include "trampoline.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "thrower.h"

// other functions    

bool detect_collision(bounding_box_t a, bounding_box_t b) {
        return (abs(a.x - b.x) * 2 < (a.width + b.width)) &&
               (abs(a.y - b.y) * 2 < (a.height + b.height));
    }
```

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bounding_box_t Trampoline::bounding_box()’
     if (detect_collision(this->bounding_box, thrower->bounding_box))
                                                                   ^
```

Other similar questions haven't helped much.

Comment: Did you mean to call `Trampoline::bounding_box()`? If so, you need to add the empty parentheses. I.e., `if (detect_collision(this->bounding_box(), thrower->bounding_box()))`

Comment: @FredLarson, thanks! that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have defined `thrower->bounding_box` as a member *function* not a member *variable*. So you need to use it as `thrower->bounding_box()`

So your code should be

```
#include "trampoline.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "thrower.h"

//other functions

void Trampoline::landed(Thrower* thrower){
    if (detect_collision(this->bounding_box, thrower->bounding_box()))
        thrower->speed.y = -2* thrower->speed.y;
  }
```